# What is the difference between GCD Dispatch Sources and select()?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, sockets, grand-central-dispatch

I've been writing some code that replaces some existing:

```
while(runEventLoop){
  if(select(openSockets, readFDS, writeFDS, errFDS, timeout) > 0){
    // check file descriptors for activity and dispatch events based on same 
  }
}
```

socket reading code.  I'd like to change this to use a GCD queue, so that I can pop events on to the queue using dispatch_async instead of maintaining a "must be called on next iteration" array.  I also am already using a GCD queue to /contain/ this particular action, hence wanting to devolve it to a more natural GCD dispatch form. ( not a while() loop monopolizing a serial queue )

However, when I tried to refactor this into a form that relied on dispatch sources fired from event handlers tied to DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_READ and DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_WRITE on the socket descriptors, the library code that depended on this scheduling stopped working.  My first assumption is that I'm misunderstanding the use of DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_READ and DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_WRITE - I had assumed that they would yield roughly the same behavior as calling select() with those socket descriptors.

Do I misunderstand GCD dispatch sources? Or, regarding the refactor, am I using it in a situation where it is not best suited?

Comment: You should show your code - what you did try. In the meanwhile, Mike Ash has some sample code to check - http://www.mikeash.com/svn/GCDWeb/GCDWeb.m - GCD web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: none. There are no differences, both GCD dispatch sources and `select()` do the same thing: they notify the user that a specific kernel event happened or that a particular condition holds true.

Note that, on a mac or iOS device you should not use `select()`, but rather the more advanced `kqueue()` and `kevent()` (or `kevent64()`).

You may certainly convert the code to use GCD dispatch sources, but you need to be careful not to break other code relying on this. So, this needs a complete inspection of the whole code handling signals, file descriptors, socket and all of the other low level kernel events.

May be a simpler solution could be to maintain the original code, simply adding GCD code in the part that react to events. Here, you dispatch events on different queues depending on the particular type of event.

Comment: I agree, one difference is that with GCD you can modularize your code into separate state machines with independent dispatch queues associated with each source. I am not sure but I guess internally GCD could be using something similar to select itself.

Comment: Can you be more specific about why kqueue() is better than select() on  iOS?  From my brief exploration, it looks like kqueue() is preferred when you have many events to monitor, but is there any reason to believe it is better than select() on an fdset with single fd? In that case, it seems like the semantics are nearly identical, so not sure why performance would be different?

Comment: The performances are actually different: just try it for yourself. You should see that, even for a single file descriptor with intense activity, kqueue() performs better. Probably, Apple did not insisted too much improving the old select() implementation. The new queue() system call is much more powerful and performs better. The only reason I see to use select() is that you have legacy code that you don't want to update.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try it.  I didn't do that right away because I figured it might be some work to set up proper test case and measurement.  I do have legacy code and other platforms to support, but this should drop in easy.  What I am actually hoping for is better responsiveness on the timeout parameter, though perhaps that is mainly function of calling thread priority.  Too bad iOS does not support EVFILT_TIMER which sounds like it would be exactly what I need.